# Aspnetboilerplate: Configure login path for redirect on core mvc template

Tags: c#, configuration, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, aspnetboilerplate

Sorry if this is straightforward, but I'm having a real block with this one.

I'm trying to move all the standard views and controllers from aspnetboilerplate's Module Zero (Core + MVC + jQuery) into a new area (Admin) and want to make sure the redirect for login on unauthorized view goes to /Admin/Login as opposed to /Account/Login, which is the default.

Any help really appreciated.

Dale

## Update

Here is the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //MVC
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
    });

    IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);
    AuthConfigurer.Configure(services, _appConfiguration);

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Admin/Login");

    services.AddScoped<IWebResourceManager, WebResourceManager>();

    //Configure Abp and Dependency Injection
    return services.AddAbp<CrowdsiteWebMvcModule>(options =>
    {
        //Configure Log4Net logging
        options.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
            f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config")
        );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure that in [Startup.cs](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/63f6e3b6147b6df7a08b09a53dad562c57dac17c/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/Startup/Startup.cs#L41-L42):

```
IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);
AuthConfigurer.Configure(services, _appConfiguration);

// Add this line:
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Admin/Login");
```

Related docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x

Comment: I just downloaded a new template to try and this answer works perfectly fine.

Comment: What version on the template?

Comment: v3.4.0 (ASP.NET Core 2.x + .NET Core + MVC + jQuery)

Comment: Yeah, works fine on that solution but doesn't on v3.4.0 Asp.net Core2 + .net 4.6.1 + MVC + JQuery) - which we are using?

Comment: Please mention the specific template in your question.

Comment: Will do, sorry about that